# I want to search a user inputed string in a database and display all possible results

Tags: c#, sql, database

A user inputs a keyword into a textbox which must be searched in the database which is connected to c# using Connection String, I want to search in the database and display all the possible occurrence of the keyword which the user inputs.

After clicking the button, I get the error message `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` which points to the line `"ResultsQuery = Request.QueryString[TextBox1.Text].Split(' ');"`

```
    public string[] ResultsQuery;
    public int i;
    public string criteria;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            string connString = @"Data Source=ITLAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=trial;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection connStudent = new SqlConnection(connString);
            connStudent.Open();


            ResultsQuery = Request.QueryString[TextBox1.Text].Split(' ');

            foreach (string textbox1 in ResultsQuery)
            {
                 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria))
                    criteria +="  OR ";

                     criteria += "SearchName LIKE '%" + textbox1 + "%' ";
            }

            string SqlInsertStatement = @"select * from trial.dbo.Student where Student.SearchName where '" + criteria;
            SqlCommand cmdTxt = new SqlCommand(SqlInsertStatement, connStudent);
            SqlDataReader dtrACode = cmdTxt.ExecuteReader();
            dtrACode.Read();


                try
                {
                    if ((dtrACode["SearchName"].ToString().Trim().Length != 0))
                    {

                    }
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(dtrACode["SearchName"].ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add("NO RECORD FOUND!");


                }


                connStudent.Close();
                connStudent.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: what is in QueryString and what is the text you gave in TextBox1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the query string value exists before you try and retrieve it, like this:

```
if (Request.QueryString[TextBox1.Text] != null) {
    ResultsQuery = Request.QueryString[TextBox1.Text].Split(' ');    
}
```

Comment: it is now working without errors but the search is not working when i press the button it does not display any results

Comment: @lizasamson - sounds like a new question, related to your query and not related to the `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` error you were receiving.

Comment: @lizasamson - if you feel my answer helped you, then feel free to accept the answer and up-vote, when you are able to. :-)

Comment: should i post another question?

Comment: @lizasamson - yes, you should post another question detailing what your current SQL string is that you are sending to the database. I would also recommend attempting to run the query against the database in SQL Server Management Studio, because the first thing people will ask is if you have tried to run the query that does not work. :-)

Comment: yes the query is working. when i run it in sql server, it displays exactly what i want buy it does not work when i used it in c#

Comment: @lizasamson - post a new question with your corrected code and show an example query that works in SQL Server Management Studio, but returns no results in your code.